# How can I store an identifier (`proc_macro::Ident`) as a constant to avoid repeating it?

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I am writing a procedural macro and I need to emit a very long identifier multiple times (potentially [because of hygiene](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59618213/2408867), for example). I use `quote!` to create `TokenStream`s, but I don't want to repeat the long identifier over and over again!

For example, I want to generate this code:

```
let very_long_ident_is_very_long_indeed = 3;
println!("{}", very_long_ident_is_very_long_indeed);
println!("twice: {}", very_long_ident_is_very_long_indeed + very_long_ident_is_very_long_indeed);
```

I know that I can create an `Ident` and interpolate it into `quote!`:

```
let my_ident = Ident::new("very_long_ident_is_very_long_indeed", Span::call_site());
quote! {
    let #my_ident = 3;
    println!("{}", #my_ident);
    println!("twice: {}", #my_ident + #my_ident);
}
```

So far so good, but I need to use that identifier in many functions all across my code base. I want it to be a `const` that I can use everywhere. However, this fails:

```
const FOO: Ident = Ident::new("very_long_ident_is_very_long_indeed", Span::call_site());
```

With this error:

```
error[E0015]: calls in constants are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
 --> src/lib.rs:5:70
  |
5 | const FOO: Ident = Ident::new("very_long_ident_is_very_long_indeed", Span::call_site());
  |                                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0015]: calls in constants are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
 --> src/lib.rs:5:20
  |
5 | const FOO: Ident = Ident::new("very_long_ident_is_very_long_indeed", Span::call_site());
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I doubt that those functions will be marked `const` any time soon.

I could make the string itself a constant:

```
const IDENT: &str = "very_long_ident_is_very_long_indeed";
```

But then wherever I want to use the identifier, I need to call `Ident::new(IDENT, Span::call_site())`, which would be pretty annoying. I want to just write `#IDENT` in my `quote!` invocation. Can I somehow make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fortunately, there is a way!

The interpolation via `#` in `quote!` works via [the `ToTokens` trait](https://docs.rs/quote/1.0.2/quote/trait.ToTokens.html). Everything implementing that trait can be interpolated. So we just need to create a type that can be constructed into a constant and which implements `ToTokens`. The trait uses types from `proc-macro2` instead of the standard `proc-macro` one.

```
use proc_macro2::{Ident, Span, TokenStream};


struct IdentHelper(&'static str);

impl quote::ToTokens for IdentHelper {
    fn to_tokens(&self, tokens: &mut TokenStream) {
        Ident::new(self.0, Span::call_site()).to_tokens(tokens)
    }
}
```

Now you can define your identifier:

```
const IDENT: IdentHelper = IdentHelper("very_long_ident_is_very_long_indeed");
```

And directly use it in `quote!`:

```
quote! {
    let #IDENT = 3;
}
```

([Full example](https://gist.github.com/LukasKalbertodt/90ce248857f900584b33f290c0850bee))